# Named-Native Query's parameters not detected in JPA 1.0

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jboss-4.2.x, jpa-1.0

I using Named native query in orm.xml.

I wrote a query to fetch Ids from a particular table. Since I just want to return the result, I wrote a dummy result set mapping.

I get the following error :

**could not locate named parameter [1]**

But this way of declaring parameters works fine while we write the query in Java file using String concatenation. What might be the problem ?

*Here is the part of my orm.xml*

```
    <named-native-query name="transactionIDs" result-set-mapping="dummy">
        <query>
                SELECT txn_master.id FROM txn_master txn_master
                LEFT JOIN  transaction txn_detail ON txn_detail.master_id = txn_master.id
                WHERE txn_detail.created between ? AND ?
        </query>
</named-native-query>


<sql-result-set-mapping name="dummy">
      <column-result name="bla" />
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

But I get the error :

```
  16:46:54,933 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  
   org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [1]
  16:46:54,933 ERROR [STDERR]   at  
   org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:176)

 16:46:54,933 ERROR [STDERR]    at 
  org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:231)
```